# Excel: If the selected dates in column A and B don't match, trigger a specific drop-down list in column C

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I have a spreadsheet as follows:

[image: Spreadsheet]

In columns P and Q, the user can select dates from a drop-down list. If the selected dates match, I want the corresponding cell in column R to say "N/A." If the selected cells do NOT match, I want a drop-down list to appear in the corresponding cell in column R.

The column names are in Swedish.

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
Dim LastRow As Integer 'The last row of used range
Dim i As Integer 'Used to loop

On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'Finds the last row
On Error GoTo 0

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Q:Q")) Is Nothing Then

        For i = 2 To LastRow
            If (Year(Cells(i, 16)) = Year(Cells(i, 17)) And Month(Cells(i, 16)) = Month(Cells(i, 17)) And Day(Cells(i, 16)) = Day(Cells(i, 17))) Then
                Cells(i, 18) = "N/A"
            Else
                Cells(i, 18).Clear
                With Cells(i, 18).Validation
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3" 'Change refrence here
                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                    .ShowInput = True
                    .ShowError = True
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    End If
```

End Sub

Hey Udden, while not the greatest code ever written, this should help. You will need to change the reference to your drop down source. You can also use named range for this, just search around for this, it isn't hard. Let me know if you have any further questions. EDIT: I am just assuming you know some VBA, if you don't, press ALT+F11 then double click on the Lista A and paste in my code. See my comment in the code, which starts with "'" to figure out what reference to change.

Answer (score 0):

This could be acomplish with formulas inside `Data Validation`

In column R you select all the range that you want to have the `Data Validation` then, appears this window,

[image]

Then in the `Allow` section you select `List` and you will see this

[image]

In the source section you will write this:

```
=IF($B2<>$C2,$J$11:$J$22,$X$11)
```

Where:

`$B2` and `$C2` are the columns with the date that I want to compare, for you will be `P` and `Q`.

First List
`$J$11:$J$22` are the range with the list I want to show if the dates do NOT match.

Second List
`$X$11`, just a cell with "`N/A`" to show if the dates in `B2` and `C2` already match.

Because my logical test in the `IF` formula, says `If B2 and C2 are NOT equal, show the first list, if not (If B2 and C2 are equals) then show the secound list`

Then you can have this:

[image]